# Proof Rao-Blackwell estimator is actually an estimator

Tags: statistics

I have a conceptual question about Rao-Blackwell theorem.

The Rao-Blackwell theorem states that for an unbiased estimator $\hat\theta(X)$ of $\theta$, and a sufficient statistic $T$ for $\theta$, the new estimator $\hat\theta^* (X)$ of $\theta$,
$$\hat\theta^*(X) = E[\hat\theta(X)|T)]$$
is unbiased and has smaller variance than the original one.

I understand the proof for unbiaseness and the variance inequality, but I don't actually understand why that $\hat\theta^*(X)$ actually is an estimator.

I suppose the proof about it is related to the sufficiency of T, not used in the other proofs.

Comment: It is a function of the observation (in this case in fact a function of the sufficient statistic, which is a function of the observation) with the same dimension as $\theta$.  What more do you want from an estimator?

Comment: Shouldn't it be independent from $\theta$?

Comment: What do you mean by *independent* from $\theta$?  You would hope that it is usually close to $\theta$

Comment: @PhilMett $T$ is a statistic, which by definition makes it independent of $\theta$. So of course $E(\hat\theta \mid T)=g(T)$ (say, for some function $g$) is independent of $\theta$, which is why it is a statistic in the first place.